# how to make synchronous call to function in node.js?

Tags: node.js, promise

i have written this code in node.js

```
var zipEntries = zip.getEntries();
zipEntries.forEach(function (zipEntry) {

        if (zipEntry.entryName.toString().indexOf('.csv') > -1) {
            var data = zip.readFile(zipEntry.entryName.toString());
            zip.extractEntryTo(zipEntry.entryName.toString(), "./csvdata", false, true);
            var filepath = zipEntry.entryName.toString();
            filepath = filepath.replace('largecsvzip2/', '');
            **some_function**("./csvdata/" + filepath);
        }
    });
```

problem is that function i.e some_function in the loop must be call after previous execution of some_function finish.

currently function calls before its previous execution finish.

Comment: i know about promises. how can i use promise here?

Comment: When you say some of these functions are async. Do these functions return a promise or you need to supply a callback function to it? I guess for a start you might want to let the readers know which function there is async.

Comment: no this functions are not return anything

Comment: First of all, the behavior that you describe is impossible in a single-threaded environment. Second of all, it is impossible to imagine what behavior you are indeed experiencing and answer your question not knowing how does the mysterious `some_function()` work. Does it return a promise? Does it take a callback?

Comment: i am new to nodejs. so i dont know this things much

Comment: `var data = zip.readFile(zipEntry.entryName.toString());` I doubt this function would give you back the actual data. Maybe it is returning you a promise?

Comment: What exact zip library are you using?  We have to be able to see the documentation for that library to know how to help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use async eachSeries -- [async docs](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachSeries)

Answer (score 0):

U need use `promise.all` for u solution. [api promises](https://www.promisejs.org/api/)

add all your async function to stack and use `promise.all`

Comment: `promise.all` will not help OP as he is looking at performing calls in a sequential matter. You might want to look at modifying your solution to be `promise.then` instead?